# JQuery Mobile 1.4 text inputs widths

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've recently switched to JQuery Mobile 1.4 and although overall I prefer it to 1.3 I'm having a lot of formatting issues.

I want to have a list of changeable values and this is the code I'm using.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="name">Amount</label>
<input type="number" name="name1" id="name1" value="" style="width:75px"/>
</div>
```

I added the width:75px to see if it would work but all it does is move the number select arrows - it doesn't actually make the text box smaller.

So the text boxes are as wide as their container but only by a limited amount. It looks fine on the computer but on a mobile you end up with the label text on top of the textbox if you constrain it too much.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
.ui-input-text{
    width: 75px !important;
}
```

jQM puts a DIV around the input with the class .ui-input-text, so you need to set its width and the input will then fill it.  You may want to make your CSS more specific if you don't want all text inputs set to 75px;

Comment: I have tried using "#myid{
    width: 75px !important;
}"  but it could not work. How do I control individual element?

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer more complete. I had a hard time controlling the size of the textbox beside the label the image below is what I was trying to achieve. Setting all textbox to a particular size is sometimes not relevant. A situation like Address and Zip will make the UI look too long on a desktop but only ok on mobile.

[image]

The code below is how I achieve it. It may look easy for someone who is good at CSS by for me a beginner, it is very helpful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>

#id1 .ui-input-text { width: 150px !important }
</style>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" >
      </div>
      <div class="ui-field-contain" id="id1">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" >
      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>

    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also use the data-wrapper-class attribute of jQM to assign a class to the input's container div: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qvqafvbx/  APIdoc: http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/#option-wrapperClass